# Changing access modifier of CreateRow method of GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to change the access modifier in c# asp.net for a dll file.

For example, i am trying to use CreateRow of GridView in C# asp.net and the error i get is

"System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(int, int, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowType, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowState)
is inaccessible due to its protection level"

I checked the modifier and it is protected. When i tried to change, it says readonly and cannot be changed. Is it possible?

UPDATE: I am trying to get a dataset from database and trying to bind it to gridview. Dataset might have upto 4 rows. If it has any rows less than 4 the remaining rows should be shown empty in the gridview. So i am trying to create 4 empty rows using CreateRow method and then binding each row from the dataset. I hope i am clear!

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what it is you're trying to do. There are better ways to accomplish adding a row to a GridView.

Comment: I will update the question in just a bit

Comment: @jadarnel27 I updated the question with what i am trying to do. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to anwer your original question as asked ("*Is it possible to change the access modifier in c# asp.net for a dll file*"), but the root of your question (adding empty rows to your GridView).

I think the better approach (rather than trying to call CreateRow on the GridView) is to just add empty rows to your dataset, and then bind it to your GridView.  this would be different based on what specific data type your storing your data in, but the basic steps would be:

1. Get your data from the database
2. Use logic to check how many rows there are
3. If there are less than 4 items, add additionaly (empty) items / rows to the collection where your data is stored from step 1.
4. Set GridView.DataSource to that data collection
5. Call GridView.DataBind();

To elaborate on step #3, do something like this:

```
// Get your DataSet from the database
DataSet data = getMyDataSomeHow();
// Create a blank row
object[] newRow = new object[3]; // where "3" is the number of columns in your table
newRow[0] = "";
newRow[1] = "";
newRow[2] = "";
//Add the blank row
data.Tables["myTable"].BeginLoadData();
data.Tables["myTable"].LoadDataRow(newRow, true);
data.Tables["myTable"].EndLoadData();
```

Comment: Let me try doing that! Thank you!

Comment: Can you please elaborate the step 3 a little bit, Please!!

Comment: @Ram Sure.  What are you currently storing the data you retrieve from the database in right now?

Comment: Dataset. You want me to add empty rows to the datatable and then bind it. Am i right?

Comment: @Ram Yes, that's exactly right.  Using the `DataTable.LoadDataRow` method.  I'll add a sample in a minute.

Comment: @Ram I've added a simple example.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Completely makes sense! Thank you very much for all the time @jadarnel27